# How do I programmatically rename all tables in a database and prepend/append some text to the names of all of them?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL database of tables similar to:

```
users
tests
billing
```

and i am looking for an SQL query that cycles through tables in the database and appends `application_` to the name, resulting in:

```
application_users
application_tests
application_billing
```

Comment: What have you tried? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the Operating System you are using, have you considered writing a shell script that pipes the output of "show tables" command through sed to generate a script file with the appropriate alter table commands?

```
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ more showtables.sql
show tables
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ mysql -uroot -ppassword -N test < showtables.sql | awk '{ print "alter table " $1 " rename to abc_"$1 }'
alter table conversations rename to abc_conversations
alter table foo rename to abc_foo
alter table messages rename to abc_messages
alter table t1 rename to abc_t1
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$
```

You can send that output to some .sql file and then execute it using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

```
RENAME TABLE  
   `database`.`table_1234` TO `database`.`new_table_1234`,  
   `database`.`table_3456` TO `database`.`new_table_3456`;
```

Comment: Is there a way to have that iterate over all tables in the database?

Comment: Write dynamic SQL that gets the names from `information_schema.tables`.

Comment: @gilbertbw: Can you edit your question to specify that you want to rename *all* tables in a database? There are now two people who have suggested the same wrong solution because they misinterpreted your question in the same way.

Comment: @Barmar could you give me an example of SQL that would do this? I am rather new to SQL!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done much dynamic SQL. I'd have to google it to find the proper syntax. If I can google, so can you.